# Audio bluez input extremely low audio output

Tags: bluez

I've previously used bluez to setup my raspberry pi as a bluetooth speaker and this has worked well Recently, it has stopped giving an output. I've checked the following:

1. Checking with pavucontrol showed that the phone under input devices
   is recording a waveform
2. Checking the output tab on pavucontrol showed that a very low volume
   output was seen, even though all volume is set to 100%
3. I don't know if it makes a difference, but 'sudo systemctl status
   bluetooth' returns this error: 'Jul 31 20:48:37 zpi
   bluetoothd[8483]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway:
   rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)'
4. Running a trial .wav file outputs sound at the normal volume, with
   no issues at all.
5. Amixer shows that all output is set to 100%
6. Using alsamixer and pressing f6 and changing to the USB Dac shows
   that the PCM is set to 0 with a dbGain of -54, -54. Changing this,
   however has no effect on the output.
7. Running an output from any other source (i.e. USB turntable, tizonia
   spotify streaming) outputs music at the normal volume (i.e. not
   super low)

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: This was a bit of a stupid question as I had previously reduced the output volume on Tizonia and that was somehow inherited as my default volume. Re-launching tizonia and maxing the volume output solved this... I'll leave this here just in case.

Comment: See: https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il/issues/593